# Python Selection Sort issues

Tags: python, sorting

So i have a code block here for selection sort in python. I understand the concept of selection sort. Search for the minimum in the list, swap it with the first value in the list and repeat for the remaining elements in the list. I've tried writing that out but instead of the sorted list `[2,3,4,7,9]`i'm getting` [3,7,4,9,9]. I've tried tracing but i cant find the errors. I would really appreciate your help in this.

```
T = [3,7,4,9,2]
for i in range (len(T)-1):
    minIndex = i
    minimum = T[minIndex]
    for j in range(i+1, len(T)):
        if minimum  > T[j]:
            minIndex = j


    temp = T[i]
    T[i]= minimum
    T[minIndex] = temp

print(T)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    if minimum  > T[j]:
        minIndex = j
```

Only the index is updated, the `minimum` value needs to be updated as well:

```
    if minimum  > T[j]:
        minIndex = j
        minimum = T[j]    # <---
```